# Prove that $4x(x-5)^3 + (x-5)^4=5(x-5)^3(x-1)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given the expression $x(x-5)^4$ I need to differentiate it. Upon using the product rule followed by the chain rule I get this answer, $4x(x-5)^3 + (x-5)^4$. The answer in the back of the book is $5(x-5)^3(x-1)$. According to wolfram alpha, these answers are equal to each other. I have not the foggiest idea how powers can be reduced in this fashion and an equivalent expression obtained. It almost seems like it is somehow turned into a quotient expression and cancellation occurs. What algebra am I not understanding? Thank you.

Comment: Factor out $(x-5)^3$ is your answer to get $(x-5)^3(4x+x-5)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\displaystyle4x(x-5)^3+(x-5)^4=(x-5)^3(4x+(x-5))=5(x-5)^3(x-1)$

Comment: thank you, apparently my factoring of powers greater than 2 need work